# Comparing two dictionaries and multiplying their values

Tags: python

I can't seem to be able to fix this problem in python, and I would be really happy if someone could help me.
I basically have two dictionaries.

```
dict_a = { "poop" : 2, "eggs": 3, "pee": 3, "debt": 4 }
dict_b = { "poop" : 10, "pee": 9}

for word, number in dict_a.items():
     if word in dict_b.keys():
           points = dict_a[word] * dict_b[key]
prints(points)
```

My problem is that it doesnt seem to work hehe. When I'm comparing my two dictionaries, even if they have the same keys, they do not match. 
Is there any easier way in seeing if two dictionaries have the same keys, and then multiply the keys' values with each other?

I want the result to be
points = 47
Because poop has its values 2*10 and pee has 3*9.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: is `dict_a[ord]` a typo?

Comment: also, you're only setting `points` equalt to the multiple of the value. you're not saving the multiplied value. You'd need to do something like `dict_a[word] *= dict_b[word]`.

Comment: Could you show exactly what result you expect for the specified `dict_a` and `dict_b`? Do you want to change the values in one of them, or create a new dict, or exactly what?

Comment: I expected the result:
points = 47

Comment: being that poop's two values are 2*10 and pee is 3*9.

Comment: So, you want to add up all those products? Hint: where in your code is the part where you attempt to do the addition?

Comment: Karl, that is true I forgot to add that.. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
def mult_dicts(dict1, dict2):
  result_dict = {}
  for word in dict1:
    result_dict[word] = dict1[word]
    if word in dict_b:
      result_dict[word] *= dict2[key]
    else:
      result_dict[word] = dict2[key]
  return result_dict
```

Or, if you only want it to contain entries when the key is in both dictionaries:

```
def mult_dicts(dict1, dict2):
  result_dict = {}
  for word in dict1:
    if word in dict_b:
      result_dict[word] = dict1[word] * dict2[key]
  return result_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
>>> for x in set(dict_a.keys() + dict_b.keys()):
...     print(x,dict_b.get(x,1)*dict_b.get(x,1))
... 
('pee', 27)
('poop', 20)
('debt', 4)
('eggs', 3)
```

if you want a dictionary:

```
>>> { x:dict_a.get(x,1)*dict_b.get(x,1) for x in set(dict_a.keys() + dict_b.keys())}
{'pee': 27, 'poop': 20, 'debt': 4, 'eggs': 3}
```

if you want list:

```
>>> [ [x,dict_a.get(x,1)*dict_b.get(x,1)] for x in set(dict_a.keys() + dict_b.keys())]
[['pee', 27], ['poop', 20], ['debt', 4], ['eggs', 3]]
```

total points:

```
>>> sum([ dict_a.get(x,1)*dict_b.get(x,1) for x in set(dict_a.keys()) & set(dict_b.keys())])
47
```

remove sum to see values:

```
>>> [ dict_a.get(x,1)*dict_b.get(x,1) for x in set(dict_a.keys()) & set(dict_b.keys())]
[27, 20]
```

Comment: What if `dict_b` contains keys that `dict_a` doesn't have ?

Comment: then add key first :)

Comment: Your example should be updated to reflect that fact or it might be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming, of course, that non present values have a cardinality of 1.

```
dict_a = { "poop" : 2, "eggs": 3, "pee": 3, "debt": 4 }
dict_b = { "poop" : 10, "pee": 9}
result = {}

for key in set(dict_a).union(dict_b):
    result[key] = dict_a.get(key, 1) * dict_b.get(key, 1)
```

You may also use a `defaultdict` to prevent the explicit `get(x, 1)` but its mainly a matter of preference at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
       dict_a = { "poop" : 2, "eggs": 3, "pee": 3, "debt": 4 }
       dict_b = { "poop" : 10, "pee": 9}

x=raw_input("Word: ")
if x in dict_a:
    point=dict_a[x]*dict_b[x]
print point
```

Result: word: poop

20

Edit then:

```
    dict_a = { "poop" : 2, "eggs": 3, "pee": 3, "debt": 4 }
    dict_b = { "poop" : 10, "pee": 9}


for x in dict_a:
    for y in dict_b:
        point=dict_a[x]*dict_b[y]
        print point
```

**Result:** 27
30
18
20
36
40
27
30

Comment: I dont want to user to be able to enter the key. It should see itself if the dictionaries have any words in common.